# IntelliJ IDEA cannot drop component onto form

Tags: java, intellij-idea, components, custom-controls

I'm very new to IDEA, and I wonder why my Custom Component can't be added to the GUI. I created a new project and added a new GUI and a new class which is a Component.

Here's the code for the Component:

```
package comps;

import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * Created by danielmartin1 on 25.03.15.
 */
public class TestComp extends JLabel {
}
```

I'm using OSX Yosemite, with the JDK 1.8

Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: If you build your project with JDK 1.8, IDEA must be also running under JDK 1.8, otherwise it will not be able to load classes compiled with JDK 1.8. Either change the target language level to 1.6 or get IDEA with JDK 1.8 for Mac: http://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIU-14.1-custom-jdk-bundled.dmg. Does it help?

Comment: Please include a more detailed desription of *how* it is not working.  Are you getting an error?  Or are the components just apparently not added to the screen?  One problem could be that the positioning of the component has it outside the visible area.

Comment: Also, how are you *adding* the component to the GUI?  Perhaps you're just not adding the component at all.  It is not enough to just create a new class that extends `JPanel`; you have to *use* it.  But the only code you've included is that which *defines* the component.

Answer (score 0):

Using the custom bundled IDEA helped. Now i can add any Custom Component the GUI.
But there are now some other problems: 
First, the component doesn't look as it should in the form editor (it looks like a combobox),
and Second: My program crashes when trying to run if the layout is set to GridlayoutManager(IntelliJ). With Borderlayout selected, it is running and my component is shown (only at runtime) correctly.

So here is the code for my component:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class CustomTracker extends JComponent implements MouseListener {
/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private boolean isSelected = false;

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public String text;

public int fontSize = 13;

private ImageIcon iIBack = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/CheckBox/Tracker_Back.png"));
private ImageIcon iIButton = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/CheckBox/Tracker_Button.png"));

private ImageIcon stretchedBack, stretchedButton;

private Font fontTracker = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, fontSize);
private Font fontText = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, fontSize);
private Color textColor = new Color(103, 125, 129);
private Color buttonColor = new Color(255, 255, 255);

private int backOriginalWidth, backOriginalHeight;
private int buttonOriginalWidth, buttonOriginalHeight;
private float scale = .7f;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param text
 *            set the text of this component
 */
public CustomTracker(String text) {
    this.text = text;
    this.setSize(this.getWidth(), iIBack.getIconHeight());
    this.addMouseListener(this);

    this.backOriginalWidth = iIBack.getIconWidth();
    this.backOriginalHeight = iIBack.getIconHeight();

    this.buttonOriginalWidth = iIButton.getIconWidth();
    this.buttonOriginalHeight = iIButton.getIconHeight();

    // Stretch Back
    Image img = iIBack.getImage();
    Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance((int) (backOriginalWidth * scale), (int) (backOriginalHeight * scale), java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    stretchedBack = new ImageIcon(newimg);

    // Stretch Button
    img = iIButton.getImage();
    newimg = img.getScaledInstance((int) (buttonOriginalWidth * scale), (int) (buttonOriginalHeight * scale), java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    stretchedButton = new ImageIcon(newimg);

    // stretch font
    this.fontSize = (int)(this.fontSize * scale);
    this.fontTracker = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, fontSize);
}

/**
 * get selected value
 */
//    @Override
//    public boolean isSelected() {
//        return this.isSelected;
//    }

/**
 * set selected value
 *
 * @param selected
 *            the value
 */
public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.isSelected = selected;
}

@Override
public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
    return new Dimension(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
}

/**
 * paint the component
 *
 * @param g
 *            the graphics object
 */
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // create a Graphics2D Object
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

    // Draw Box Image
    g2d.drawImage(stretchedBack.getImage(), 0, 0, stretchedBack.getIconWidth(), stretchedBack.getIconHeight(), this);

    // Set Font-Values
    g2d.setFont(fontTracker);
    g2d.setColor(buttonColor);

    // Set text coordinates
    int x;
    int y = (int) (((iIBack.getIconHeight() / 2) + (fontSize / 2) + 1) * scale);

    if (this.isSelected == true) {
        g2d.drawImage(stretchedButton.getImage(), (int) (40 * scale), (int) (2 * scale), stretchedButton.getIconWidth(),
                stretchedButton.getIconHeight(), this);
        x = (int) (15 * scale);
        g2d.drawString("ON", x, y);
    } else {
        g2d.drawImage(stretchedButton.getImage(), 0, (int) (2 * scale), stretchedButton.getIconWidth(), stretchedButton.getIconHeight(), this);
        x = (int) (37 * scale);
        g2d.drawString("OFF", x, y);
    }

    // Draw ON or OFF
    g2d.drawString(getText(), (int)((iIBack.getIconWidth() + 10) * scale), y);

    // Set Font-Values
    g2d.setFont(fontText);
    g2d.setColor(textColor);

    // Set new y-Position
    y = ((stretchedBack.getIconHeight() / 2) + (fontSize / 2) + 1);

    // draw the text behind the Control
    g2d.drawString(getText(), stretchedBack.getIconWidth() + 10, y);

    // dispose Variables
    g2d.dispose();
}

@Override
public void setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    super.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
}

/**
 * set the text of this component
 *
 * @param text
 *            the text to display
 */
public void setText(String text) {
    setText(text);
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    this.isSelected = !this.isSelected;
    repaint();
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Does anyone know a solution for these problems?